# SQL length rest of character

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL I declare the `Name nvarchar(5)`, `Dept varchar(5)`

```
sql> 
select Name,Dept from tablename
```

---

```
Name      Dept
ABC       CD
```

but I want to display like this

---

```
Name      Dept
ABCXX     CDXXX
```

because the variable length display rest of length should be 'XXXXX'

Comment: SQL Server? Or SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try padding with `'XXXXX'`:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(Name + 'XXXXX', 5) AS Name,
    LEFT(Dept + 'XXXXX', 5) AS Dept
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo